# ALSA setting microphone levels

Tags: alsa, audio-recording

I have an USB handset that I am trying to record from and depending on settings I want to mute the device. The only controls that amixer provides is:

`amixer -D hw:1
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]`

As can be seen there isn't a lot of controls to this handset, which as a speaker at one end of the handset and a microphone at the other, like an old time telephone receiver.

I know I can control the volume using a 
`type softvol` PCM device but this only allows the speaker volume to be controlled. What I need is a way to mute the microphone with something similar to turning down the recording level. Is there a way do this in asound.conf? The only examples that I can find are to do with a softvol on the output not the input. So is it possible to mute the microphone based on what the device tells its controls are or is there a softvol equivalent on input?

Comment: Do you have Pulseaudio on whatever computer you are using? This is installed by default today on most distros, and if you record via Pulseaudio, you'll already have a mic volume and mute, possibly without modifying anything. Also, googling seems to indicate that you can use softvol on a mic, so that's what I'd try next.

Comment: We don't run PulseAudio. We have removed it from our deployed systems. That is why I need a method using ALSA to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A `softvol` plugin works just fine for this, but you have to tell ALSA that it's supposed to be controlling the recording volume. The way you do this is not documented, but if you append  `Capture Volume` to the name (preceding space and capitalization are important) it will be parsed as a `softval` plugin that controls the microphone recording level.

Combined with folding the resulting device into `default`, this was my resulting `.asoundrc`:

```
pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmix"
        slave.rate 48000
    }
    capture.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "mic_control"
    }
}

pcm.mic_control {
    type            softvol
    slave {
        pcm         "hw:2,0"
    }
    control {
        name        "Softmute Capture Volume"
        card        2
    }
    max_dB 10.0
    min_dB -100.0
}
```

Note that the suffix is stripped, so it shows up as `Softmute` in e.g. `amixer`:

```
$ amixer -c 2 scontrols
Simple mixer control 'Softmute',0
```